# 10 inch rough toilet but heating baseboard is in the way

Tags: toilet, rough-in

Just moved into a new house. Need to replace the toilet. It is a 10 inch rough from the wall, however there is a heating baseboard in the way. There is a toilet there now and the back of the base of the toilet doesn't extend all the way back to the wall and that's why it fits. I've gone everywhere and cannot find a toilet that doesn't extend back to the wall. The existing toilet seems to be from the 80's or 90's.

Anyone know where online I can find a toilet whose base does not extend all the way back to the wall so it fits with the baseboard heating?

Comment: Have a look here https://toiletreviewer.com/10-inch-rough-in-toilets/

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What type of baseboard is this? (Electric or hydronic?)

Answer (score 4):

I had a weird offset flange in a bathroom where I replaced a toilet and like you, couldn't come close to finding one at my locals shops. At this point one option is to visit a plumbing supply outlet and see if they can help. They are the ones who know about these specialty items.

Comment: You might want to add that OP should take at least one photograph, along with measurements if they go this route. Takes a lot of the guesswork out of things for the plumbing shop staff.

Comment: @stevieb  Thanks, this would certainly make everyone's job easier.+